# Having trouble transforming an ar-EG currency string back to a normal number in Silverlight

Tags: c#, string, silverlight-4.0, localization, globalization

using Silverlight I am having trouble with the following code:

```
        CultureInfo culture = new CultureInfo("ar-EG");
        CultureInfo invCulture = CultureInfo.InvariantCulture;

        Result.Text = String.Format(culture.NumberFormat, "{0:C}", 70000000.00);

        // Does Not Work
        //Result2.Text = String.Format(invCulture.NumberFormat, "{0}", double.Parse(Result.Text, invCulture));

        // Does Not Work
        //Result2.Text = String.Format(culture.NumberFormat, "{0}", double.Parse(Result.Text, culture.NumberFormat));

        // Does Not Work
        //Result2.Text = Convert.ToString(Decimal.Parse(Result.Text.Replace(" ", ""), NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowCurrencySymbol | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite));
```

Ultimately I'd like prove that I can transform a number to the Egyptian (Arabic) currency formatted string and then get my original number again.

Any time I try to convert my number back to the original double or decimal I receive an FormatException error 'Input string was not in a correct format.'.

Any help please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You won't be able to convert the output string back to a number using `double.Parse` as that expects the input to be purely numeric.

If you want the value to go backwards and forwards from a number to a formatted string put the formatting in the XAML:

```
<TextBlock Text={Binding NumericValue, StringFormat=c, Mode=TwoWay} />
```

[Source](http://www.designersilverlight.com/2010/05/28/silverlight-4-binding-and-stringformat-in-xaml/)

Given that you're not in XAML you'll need to strip the currency symbol off the text first. You can get the currency symbol from the [`RegionInfo.CurrencySymbol` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.globalization.regioninfo.currencysymbol%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) as well as `culture.NumberFormat.CurrencySymbol` and then remove that from the formatted text before passing to `double.Parse`.

As Mr Young points out in his comment, there is an overload of [`Decimal.Parse`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s84kdbzx.aspx) that takes a `String` and `IFormatProvider` which provide additional information about the string - such as the fact it contains a currency symbol.

Comment: Yeah, that would be nice - except where I need to happen is far far away from anything that would be a XAML library (think base class for a SOAP communication library that is compiled in Silverlight).

Comment: @Mr Young - ah. In that case you need to strip the currency symbol off first.

Comment: This also seemed to work. decimal val = Decimal.Parse(Result.Text, NumberStyles.Currency, culture.NumberFormat);
            Result2.Text = Convert.ToString(val);